# extract http request response and proceed to next http request by using while controller

Tags: jmeter

I want to use while controller to keep sending GET HTTP Request and only proceed to next POST HTTP Request when the GET response `"model_name": "Model-Test-20220221-0001"`

- POST HTTP Request - paramter `model_name = Model-Test-${variable}-${counter}`
- While Controller

  - GET HTTP Request. sample GET response at below

    - Json Extractor
- POST HTTP Request only when While Controller found the exact `model_name`.

**JSON Extractor:**

```
Names of created variable: modelname
Json path expressions: I have tried this but failed 
$..valid_model_list[?(@.model_name = ${Model-Test-${variable}-${counter}})]
```

This is sample HTTP Request response:

```
{
  "message": "success", 
  "valid_model_list": [
    {
      "meta_data": {
        "corpus_list": [
          "test1"
        ], 
        "id": "0c36effa244b4f6596d10f9e675303e1", 
        "sample_rate": 16000, 
        "split_ratio": {
          "test": 40, 
          "train": 60
        }, 
      "model_name": "Model-Test-20220221-0001", 
      "status": "ok"
    }, 
    {
      "meta_data": {
        "corpus_list": [
          "test1"
        ], 
        "id": "0c36effa244b4f6596d10f9e675303e1", 
        "sample_rate": 16000, 
        "split_ratio": {
          "test": 40, 
          "train": 60
        }, 
      "model_name": "Model-Test-20220221-0002", 
      "status": "ok"
    }
    }
    ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're "unsure" as well as we don't know what you're trying to achieve.

1. JSON Extractor can extract values from the **response**, it's not possible to use it to extract values from the request, moreover you should "know" what you're sending in the request and extracting values from the response is the essential part of the [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) process
2. If you're looking for a JSONPath expression extracting the `model_name` attribute value you're supposed to provide full JSON. There is a [Deep Scan operator](https://com) so you should be able to use something like:

   ```
   $..model_name
   ```

   but if there are more than 1 matches you might need to limit the output with [Filter Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators)

More information:

- [JsonPath Getting Started](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started)
- [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)

Comment: I updated main post. $..model_name will get all response in the list? how do I just get a specific?

Comment: what did you mean "JSON Extractor can extract values from the response, it's not possible to use it to extract values from the request"???? i thought JSON extractor can help me to look up specific json key+value.

Comment: I have flagged your comment above. this is a technical forum instead of English grammar forum.